# "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression

Tags: nginx

I've developed a URL shortening web application.

It consists of two separate docker containers: one containing the backend REST api and another containing the frontend static website.

These two containers are linked to an nginx container.
The configuration for this nginx container is below:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    upstream api {
        server short-url:8080;
    }

    upstream frontend {
        server short-url-frontend:8081;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 860;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    server {
        listen 80;
        root    /user/share/nginx/html;

        location /urlshortener/v1 {
            proxy_pass         http://api/urlshortener/v1;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location ~ ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+) {
            rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+) /$1
            proxy_pass         http://api/urlshortener/v1;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://frontend;
            proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for   $remote_addr;
        }
    }

}
```

If a url ends with `/urlshortening/v1`, I'm proxying to the backend.

If a url starts with `/`, I'm proxying to the frontend.

Shortened urls e.g. `/3xTy` or `/a0q` need to be proxied to the backend so that the user can be navigated to the original url. In order to do this, I've defined a location with a regular expression.

```
location ~ ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+) {
    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+) /$1
   proxy_pass         http://api/urlshortener/v1;
}
```

This block of code gives me the following error:

> 2018/11/17 16:47:03 [emerg] 1#1: "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:36

I've gone through several [examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/nginx-location-examples/) and reviewed a number of [answers](https://serverfault.com/a/693951) and I believe that the configuration I have should work. Can someone please explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Your proxy receives a request for `/3xTy`, what is the full URI to be passed upstream? `http://api/urlshortener/v1/3xTy`?

Comment: @RichardSmith: Yes, that is what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Remove the `rewrite` statement and try: `proxy_pass http://api/urlshortener/v1/$1;`

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Why was the `rewrite` statement not applicable in this case? If you could write your comment as the answer, I'd upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you use a URI with a `proxy_pass` statement within a *regular expression* `location`, you need to build the entire URI using one or more variables. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

So the alternatives are to (1), capture the URI from the `location` expression and add it to the `proxy_pass` statement. For example:

```
location ~ ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+) {
    proxy_pass http://api/urlshortener/v1/$1;
}
```

Or (2), use `proxy_pass` without a URI part, and construct the desired URI using a `rewrite...break`. For example:

```
location ~ ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+) {
    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+) /urlshortener/v1/$1 break; 
    proxy_pass http://api;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Answer (score 11):

I was getting same error and the correct answer could not be helping in my situation. here was my problematic configs:

```
# proxying wordpress static files
location ~* (((product|blog|product-category)\/.*)|(\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|woff2|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)))$ {
    proxy_pass https://mainhost.cdkeysell.ir/;
    ...
}
```

so after comparing it with my other wesite with similar configs without such error I found this could be simply solved by removing the latter `/` at end of `proxy_pass` config:

```
# proxying wordpress static files
location ~* (((product|blog|product-category)\/.*)|(\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|woff2|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)))$ {
    # proxy_pass https://mainhost.cdkeysell.ir/; ==> final `/` caused error
    proxy_pass https://mainhost.cdkeysell.ir;
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, removing `/` at the end solved by issue.